# Getting meaningful Syntax-errors from antlr parser

Tags: syntax-error, antlr

I have created a Script-Interpreter for .Net using Antlr. It works pretty fine, but the Syntax-Errors it generates are horrible.
The Library in an early development stage can be found [here](https://github.com/wylermat/Scripting-with-MS-Dotnet) and the used grammar is based on this [ecma-Script grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/ecmascript/ECMAScript.g4).

Now the big Problem is, that when i have a large scriptfile and i have an object-definition that says

```
obj = { var1 = "hello"
        var2 = "world};
```

i would expect a message saying "Syntax Error at line xyz ',' expected.
But instead a get a list of hundred no viable alternative at xyz for every follow-up error that was caused by my missing comma.

Is there a way to get the one error that is caused by the missing comma? it would also be totally ok, if it would complain about the unexpected var2 token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use 2 approaches for this:

- You check whether you recognize an error that will most likely cause a ton of following "errors" and suppress all errors afterwards from being displayed. So you have to fix that error first before you get more errors. However this will not change the cryptic messages ANTLR generates...
- You add some common errors alternatives directly in to your grammar and notify the error listener when they are invoked. With that you can specify the error message yourself. For further reference on this topic you can either refer to the `Definitive ANTLR 4 reference` that has a chapter about this or you can have a look at [a grammar of mine](https://github.com/Krzmbrzl/SQF-grammar/blob/master/SQF.g4#L106) that uses this approach for unbalanced brackets.

When using the second approach you should also get rid of the following misproduced "errors" as the grammar can match the given input successfully and can therefore continue properly.
Therefore I would strongly suggest the second approach to you

Comment: Tank you very much. I have already tried to use the first approach. The problem is, that it is not possible to get the "initial error that caused all the others" just like that. Anyway, your second approach works perfectly and i was able to alert the most common syntax-errors meaningfully with the Method you describe in your Grammar.